# ¿Cómo establecer Sublime Text 3 como el editor por defecto del sistema de control de versiones Git?

Tags: git, sublimetext3

He intentado establecer ST3 como el editor por defecto de Git pero no he podido. He seguido varios métodos que encontré la red pero ninguno dio resultado. Si alguien ha podido realizar esto por favor que me indíqueme como lo hizo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Esto no te funciona? `git config --global core.editor editor_que_quieras`. Si no pones lo que has intentado provoca que los demás demos palos de ciego :-)

Comment: probaste configurando la variable de entorno `EDITOR`? a todo esto, en que plataforma estás? win, mac, linux?

Comment: Señores, está claro lo que se pregunta y sí está asociado a programación. La pregunta es válida para el sitio. Favor de evitar votar a cerrar por desconocimiento en cómo funciona la plataforma.

Answer (score 0):

para sublime 3, en view>console 
ingresar esto

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = 'df21e130d211cfc94d9b0905775a7c0f' + '1e3d39e33b79698005270310898eea76'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

luego de ingresar eso presionas ctrl+shift+p y escribes install package, luego escribes git y presionas enter y listo!